# TypeError when scraping website with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm scraping www.tosdr.org for some data. For example I'm trying to capture the content of the `<title>` tag as follows:

```js
$.get('https://tosdr.org/', function(response) {
  var body = response.match(/<title>\[ ([\d]*?) \]<\/title>/);
  console.log(body);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Problem with this is that I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: response.match(...) is null

I shouldn't be getting this error. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The code in your question just shows `null`, not an error. That being said, [don't use Regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/519413). Use a HTML parser, then retrieve the data you want from the DOM that's generated

Comment: Well "null" isn't in the title of the site so I still consider it as an error.

Comment: To get the text try something like `$(response).find('title').text()`, however if you're getting an error that's not going to work. We need to see the actual code which creates the error in order to help you debug it

Comment: You regex would should be `.match(/<title[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/title>/)[1]`

Comment: @Carsten  That worked. Apparently I was using old regex-matching rule. Submit it as an answer and I'm gonna tick it for you.